# Hyperplane theorem of Combinatorial Nullstellensatz of N. Alon

Tags: graph-theory

I`ve got a question about the proof of Theorem 6.3 of Alon's  Combinatorial Nullstellensatz paper:
$\textbf{Theorem 6.3}$ Let $H_1,...,H_m$ be a family of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that cover all vertices of the unit cube $\{0,1\}^n$ but one. Then $m\geq n$.
$\textbf{Proof.}$ Clearly we may assume that the uncovered vertex is the all zero vector. Let $(a_i, x) = b_i$ be the equation defining $H_i$, where $x = (x_1, x_2,..., x_n)$, and $(a, b)$ is the inner product between the two vectors $a$ and $b$. Note that for every $i, b_i \neq 0$, since $H_i$ does not cover the origin. Assume the assertion is false and $m < n$, and consider the polynomial $$P(x)=(-1)^{n+m+1} \prod\limits_{j=1}^m b_j\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-1)-\prod\limits_{i=1}^m [(a_i,x)-b_i].$$
The degree of this polynomial is clearly $n$, and the coefficient of $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ in it is $(-1)^{n+m+1} \prod_{j=1}^m b_j$. Therefore, by Theorem 1.2 there is a point $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ for which $P(x) \neq 0$. This point is not the all zero vector, as $P$ vanishes on it, and therefore it is some other vertex of the cube. But in this case $(a_i, x) - b_i = 0$ for some $i$ (as the vertex is covered by some $H_i$), implying that $P$ does vanish on this point, a contradiction. $\square$
I think, that I understand the proof, but there is one problem. I asked myself, why $P(0)=0$. My considerations are as follows:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(0)&=&(-1)^{n+m+1} \prod\limits_{j=1}^m b_j\cdot(-1)^n-\prod\limits_{i=1}^m [-b_i]=(-1)^{2n}(-1)^{m+1} \prod\limits_{j=1}^m b_j-(-1)^m \prod\limits_{i=1}^m b_i\\
&=&((-1)^{m+1}-(-1)^m)\prod\limits_{i=1}^m b_i=\begin{cases} -2\cdot\prod_{i=1}^m b_i \hphantom{xxx} \text{if } m \text{ is even}\\ 2\cdot\prod_{i=1}^m b_i \hphantom{-xxx} \text{if } m \text{ is odd}\end{cases}\neq 0
\end{array}$$
Can someone spot my mistake in thinking? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo and the author meant to write $(-1)^{n+m}$ instead?

Comment: Thank you for your message. That is an option. I just thought I made a mistake because this is Noga Alon's official paper and I couldn't have imagined him making a typo.

Comment: Anyone can make a sign error, and since the proof works if the sign is corrected, I think that is the issue.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Well, then I am satisfied. Many Thanks